# How to give one Side of text button during hover?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I was trying to make a TextButton with one-sided shown when Hover on it. One of the most popular ways to decorate a button in CSS. I am facing difficulty to do in flutter.

I tried like this:

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text('About Us'),
  style: ButtonStyle(
    shape: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<OutlinedBorder>((states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
        return RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
        );
    
      } else {
        return RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
        );
      }
    }),
  ),
)
```

But there isn't any property of the button to have only one side, like container have Border.
or am I missing something out?

Comment: can you show an image of the css button you want to recreate?

Comment: https://ibb.co/WP2wwx5   like under spotlight, when you hover it's shown, else it's not there.

Comment: you mean an underline?

Comment: yes an underlineButton

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using an `InkWell` with a `DecoratedBox`.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HoveredButtonExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const HoveredButtonExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HoveredButtonExampleState createState() => _HoveredButtonExampleState();
}

class _HoveredButtonExampleState extends State<HoveredButtonExample> {
  late bool showBorder = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DecoratedBox(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: showBorder
                ? Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                  )
                : null,
          ),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            onHover: (hovered) {
              setState(() {
                showBorder = hovered;
              });
            },
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print('Text button pressed');
              },
              child: Text('Button'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: that's a nice way to implement!!

Comment: TextButton also has onHover method, so there is no need to wrap it in InkWell.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an sample code :-

```
bool showHower = false;
DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: showBorder
            ? Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 2),
              )
            : null,
      ),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        onHover: (hovered) {
          setState(() {
            showHower = hovered;
          });
        },
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
          },
          child: Text('HoverButton'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```